# Using Hebrew in Powershell

Tags: powershell, email, encoding

I'm trying to use the `Send-Mail` cmdlet with Hebrew characters in the Subject field,
but when i get the mail to my mailbox, it's jibrish.  I've tried to use the `-Encoding` parameter with different values, (intuitively i thought that Unicode would do) with no success. Can someone guide me on this?

Example:

```
$Subject = "שלום"
$Body = "Some text"

Send-MailMessage -From "sender@mail.com" -To "recipient@mail.com" -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer "some.smtp.server"
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and show how you are sending the mail. Also, including a sample of gibberish output might provide some clues about what happened to the encoding.

Comment: Check the encoding of your ps file.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```bsh
Send-MailMessage -From       "sender@mail.com" `
                 -To         "recipient@mail.com" `
                 -Subject    "שלום" `
                 -Body       "Some text" `
                 -SmtpServer "localhost" `
                 -Encoding   ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8);
```

I'm running the [smtp4dev](https://github.com/rnwood/smtp4dev) smtp server locally and the message arrives looking like this:

[image]

It's possible (although unlikely) that your target email server doesn't support encoded subjects, or it's a problem with the email client you're using to read the message.

If you can reproduce the above with smtp4dev then at least you know your code is working :-)

Comment: I get emails in with the same client and server in hebrew...

Comment: @YoavKlein - ok. so to get us some more information could you: (i) try the above and confirm if it works for you (ii) let us know what smtp server / email client you're using (iii) cut & paste the garbled subject line into your question so we can see what you're seeing

Comment: The problem is that due to security issues i'm working in an isolated LAN, so no, i can't really do all these things... :(

Comment: @YoavKlein - can you photograph and crop the garbled text, maybe? or even hand-draw it? presumably the sample text isn't sensitive? alternatively, if you try the above code does the subject look like one of these: ```×©×œ×•×``` or ```=?utf-8?B?16nXnNeV150=?=```